# Arduino Button is not on continuous Serial "1"

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

***functionality:***

Serial monitor is printing "0" at every 100ms, signalling that the buttonState is LOW.

However when user depresses the red dome button [Red Dome Button](http://www.instructables.com/id/Big-dome-push-button-LinkIt-basics-PART-1/?ALLSTEPS), it is suppose to signal that the buttonState is HIGH and at the serial monitor, it should be printing "1" at every 100ms until the user presses the red dome button again to signal that the buttonState is LOW and serial monitor is printing "0".

***Issue:***

The serial monitor is outputting "0" at every 100ms initially, and when i press the red dome button, the buttonState returns a HIGH and at the serial monitor is outputting "1". However, the serial "1" doesn't hold and it reverts back to "0" immediately.

The serial "1" will only show in serial monitor when I press on the button continuously.

Meaning:

**Correct behaviour**:

initial state-> the serial monitor will output all serial 0 until user presses the button then the serial monitor will output all serial 1 until user presses the button again then the output will then change to serial 0

**Current behaviour**:

initial state-> the serial monitor will output all serial 0 until user presses the button then the serial monitor will output serial 1 but immediately, the serial will return to 0

Hence, how do I enable the serial state to remain at serial 1 after I press the button and the serial will show 0 only when I press the button again? I need some help in that . Thank you

***Code:***

```
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() {
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Open serial port to communicate 
 }

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("1");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("0");
  }
 delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your button gets unpressed after you release it (not like a 2 states button). So you need to create your own state variable that toggles when the button is pressed.

Let's say that you want to change the state when a HIGH is detected from the button. It means that you have to detect the change from LOW to HIGH and not only if it is in HIGH mode. So to do this you need to store the last state of the button. In addition you'll need to keep an output state that toggles when a change from LOW to HIGH is detected.

In your code should be something like this:

```
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int buttonLastState = 0;
int outputState = 0;


void setup() {
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Open serial port to communicate 
}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // Check if there is a change from LOW to HIGH
  if (buttonLastState == LOW && buttonState == HIGH)
  {
     outputState = !outputState; // Change outputState
  }
  buttonLastState = buttonState; //Set the button's last state

  // Print the output
  if (outputState)
  {
     Serial.println("1");
  }
  else
  {
     Serial.println("0");
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: a 2 states button acts like a switch where once pressed by user, it will close the circuit and when depressed again, it will open the circuit. am i right in that? so apparently the physical button that i have is only an interrupt button. am i right?

Comment: I think that your button is like you're saying. Did the code work?

Comment: sorry, I would like to ask. The code suggestion that you have provided is when user happens to press the button to toggle from LOW-> HIGH and when press again from HIGH -> LOW. I would like to ask how to modify the code suggestion for the following behaviour-> when user press the button, will toggle from LOW-> HIGH but after a delay of 25s the button state will automatically toggle from HIGH -> LOW without the user pressing the button